# C Printf containing "\22"

Tags: c, printf, escaping

I need to create a string that I send via UART to a Modem that contains the three characters \22
i.e.

```
"{\22 Timestamp \22 : \22 2021-02-22T18:00:00 \22}"
```

I can manually type the string in a terminal,  but I cannot get the \22 when I create the string programmatically using C.

Is there some kind of escape sequence I need to send?

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes, otherwise you have octal escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash character `\` specifies the start of an escape sequence in strings in C.  To include a literal backslash, use `\\`.

```
"{\\22 Timestamp \\22 : \\22 2021-02-22T18:00:00 \\22}"
```